# How to compute transfer function from Laplace Transform

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, laplace-transform

My system of interest has the following EOM (V is my input variable):

$\ddot{x} = g - k_{1}V(t) + \dot{x}k_2$

Taking the Laplace with initial conditions of zero, I get:

$s^2X(s) = \frac{g}{s} - \frac{k_1V(s)}{s} + sk_2X(s)$

How do I arrive at $\frac{X(s)}{V(s)}$, the transfer function? Perhaps I'm just too tired to see how to manipulate the Laplace statement, but I don't know how to get there...

Comment: This isn't a simple linear homogeneous system, so you won't be able to come up with a transfer function.

Comment: Note that even at zero input, V=0, there is a nonzero output. So, as @JimmyK4542 you cannot determine the transfer function, unless, you set $g=0$

Comment: OK, good to know. My controls/DE theory is a touch rusty, so I didn't immediately recognize it as non-homogeneous/linear. Indeed, by nature, the system is as you say, unstable with V=0, and is only stable for a single, non-zero V. Perhaps I will model my system as it stands currently in Simulink and use some of it's tricks/auto-magic-linearization to come up with something approximate. Thank you @JimmyK4542 & @tpb261!